# FTPS through SOCKS5 Proxy in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get files from a ftps server through a socks5 proxy. As far as I could find, the ftplib does not support socks5, the urllib does not support ftps, urllib3 and requests no ftp at all.
So my question is, if there is a way to make this work?

I tried with PySocks too -

```
import socks
s = socks.socksocket()
s.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, SOCKS5_PROXY_HOST, SOCKS5_PROXY_PORT, True, SOCKS5_PROXY_USER, SOCKS5_PROXY_PW)
```

But if I just connect via s.connect(("server","port")) I am not able to fetch the files, since its using ftps